# Where does jruby log to?

Tags: jruby, jvm-arguments

I see a lot of config options like jit.logging=true, and I want to watch out for things like when the jvm gives `CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled` messages, where does jruby log this stuff? Better yet, how can I tell it which file to log to? Is it just STDOUT and STDERR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting JRuby properties that affects JIT Runtime Properties ( such as: *jruby.jit.logging*, *jruby.jit.logging*, *jruby.jit.logging* ) you get log to **standard error** (commonly abbreviated **stderr**)

You could tell  which file to log to by redirecting **stderr** to a specific file; for example:

```
jruby -J-Djruby.jit.logging=true myscript.rb  2> myfile.log
```

beware, however, *myfile.log* receives even other **stderr** outputs; i.e if *myscript.rb* 
executes statements such as:

```
$stderr.puts "print this in stderr"
```

you will see "print this in stderr" in *myfile.log*

Comment: awesome, thanks! and when i read all this stuff about the jvm writing to SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log, is that also just going to stderr and stdout?